# How to search for the pair in two lists?

Tags: python, string, list

I have two main lists which contain 10 strings each:

```
bus0 = ['North', 'North','North','North', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'west','west', 'south']
bus1 = ['East', 'west', 'south','northeast', 'west', 'south', 'northeast', 'south', 'northeast', 'northeast']
```

these lists basically contain the possible combination of the direction, so basically, the element present at 0th position in `bus0` will have the possible pair at the same position(0th) in `bus1` and the most important thing is that combination is unique, for example, you won't find `North-East` or `East-North` at any other position except at `0th position`.
I have another list that contains 10 numbers.

```
data = [12, 23, 34, 45,13, 133, 324, 475,94,66]
```

now there are two pair list which basically tells us that which pair needs to be searched in the `bus0` and `bus1`.

```
pair1 = ['north', 'north', 'south']
pair2 = ['northeast', 'west', 'east']
```

So technically there would be three pairs:

1. north-northeast  (3rd position)
2. north-west       (1st position)
3. south-east       (5th position)

Now to get the data from `data` list, I just have to pick the elements from these positions. My approach for this:

```
bus0 = ['North', 'North','North','North', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'west','west', 'south']
bus1 = ['East', 'west', 'south','northeast', 'west', 'south', 'northeast', 'south', 'northeast', 'northeast']
data = [12, 23, 34, 45,13, 133, 324, 475,94,66]

bus0 = [i.lower() for i in bus0]
bus1 = [i.lower() for i in bus1]
combine = [(i,j,k) for i,j,k in zip(bus0, bus1, data)]


pair1 = ['north', 'north', 'south']
pair2 = ['northeast', 'west', 'east']

for i  in combine:
    for k,l in zip(pair1, pair2):
        if i[0]==k and i[1]==l:
            print(i[0]+'-'+ k)
            print(i[0] + '-' + l)
            print(i[2])
```

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could created a dictionary where the keys are the sorted values of the two lists, then created a sorted values of the two pair lists and look up the values.

```
bus0 = ['North', 'North','North','North', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'west','west', 'south']
bus1 = ['East', 'west', 'south','northeast', 'west', 'south', 'northeast', 'south', 'northeast', 'northeast']
data = [12, 23, 34, 45,13, 133, 324, 475,94,66]

pair1 = ['north', 'north', 'south']
pair2 = ['northeast', 'west', 'east']


pairs = ['-'.join(sorted([x.lower(), y.lower()])) for x,y in zip(pair1,pair2)]
m = dict(zip(['-'.join(sorted([x.lower(),y.lower()])) for x,y in zip(bus0,bus1)],data))

[m[x] for x in pairs]
```

Output

```
[45, 23, 133]
```